# Delete a specific string (not line) from a text file python

Tags: python

I have a text file with two lines in a text file:

```
<BLAHBLAH>483920349<FOOFOO>
<BLAHBLAH>4493<FOOFOO>
```

Thats the only thing in the text file. Using python, I want to write to the text file so that i can take away BLAHBLAH and FOOFOO from each line. It seems like a simple task but after refreshing my file manipulation i cant seem to find a way to do it. 
Help is greatly appreciated :)

Thanks!

Comment: Is the file **really** XML?  Or HTML?  Or XHTML?  If so, please **update** the question to be more specific on what the file **really** looks like.  There are simple ways to do this if the file matches any of the standards.

Comment: Can you show us at least what have you tried yet?

Answer (score 5):

If it's a text file as you say, and not HTML/XML/something else, just use [replace](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

```
for line in infile.readlines():
    cleaned_line = line.replace("BLAHBLAH","")
    cleaned_line = cleaned_line.replace("FOOFOO","")
```

and write `cleaned_line` to an output file.

Answer (score 5):

```
f = open(path_to_file, "w+")

f.write(f.read().replace("<BLAHBLAH>","").replace("<FOOFOO>",""))
f.close()
```

Update (saving to another file):

```
f = open(path_to_input_file, "r")
output = open(path_to_output_file, "w")

output.write(f.read().replace("<BLAHBLAH>","").replace("<FOOFOO>",""))
f.close()
output.close()
```

Comment: This way, you append the corrected data to the already existing file.

Comment: In addition to glglgl, I generally consider it pretty poor form to overwrite the input file unless it's absolutely necessary. What if there's a bug somewhere in your program?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the **regular expressions module** re.

```
result_text = re.sub('<(.|\n)*?>',replacement_text,source_text)
```

The strings within **<** and **>** are identified. It is non-greedy, ie it will accept a substring of the least possible length. For example if you have **"<1> text <2> more text"**, a greedy parser would take in **"<1> text <2>"**, but a non-greedy parser takes in **"<1>"** and **"<2>"**.

And of course, your replacement_text would be '' and source_text would be each line from the file.